# XSLT copy an elements attributes unless attribute is in a given namespace

Tags: xslt

These are SVG elements, and the supplier of the SVG documents has added all kinds of extensions, that we can not use, and do not want.  So I'd like these extended attributes removed.

I'm basically using the identity transform.  I want this element:

```
<text id="1" 
      i:knockout="Off" 
      i:objectType="pointText" 
      style="font-size:16;"
     >Hi</text>
```

to copy as

```
<text id="1" style="font-size:16;">Hi</text>
```

Any help appreciated.

**Edit**

Unfortunately, the example I chose above wasn't a real one.  This one is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" 
     i:viewOrigin="-39.4106 906.6265" i:rulerOrigin="0 0" i:pageBounds="0 840 592 0" >
   <g i:extraneous="self">
   </g>
</svg>
```

and what I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     >
   <g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If you are using the identity transformation you just have to add an empty rule for those attributes with a pattern like `@i:*` (you need a proper namespace declaration, of course...)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution. :)

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but this will not remove the unwanted namespace node from the element. My solution removes this unwanted namespace node.

Comment: @Alejandra - yes, I just got this working with the correct @i:* .  It took a bit as I also have elements of type i:, and I ended up needing two patterns to match both.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "namespace::*[not(.='i:i')]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*[namespace-uri()='i:i']"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<text id="1" xmlns:i="i:i"
  i:knockout="Off"
  i:objectType="pointText"
  style="font-size:16;">Hi</text>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<text id="1" style="font-size:16;">Hi</text>
```

**UPDATE**:  The OP now has specified the exact namespace he has the prefix `"i"` bound to.

In this case a simple replace of `"i:i"` with `http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/` gives us the new solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="pUnwantedNS" select="'http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/'"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(.=$pUnwantedNS)]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
    "@*[namespace-uri()='http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**and when applied on the newly-provided XML document:**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/"
  i:viewOrigin="-39.4106 906.6265"
  i:rulerOrigin="0 0"
  i:pageBounds="0 840 592 0" >
    <g i:extraneous="self"></g>
</svg>
```

**the wanted, correct result is again produced**:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g />
</svg>
```

Comment: `namespace::*[not(namespace-uri()='i:i')]` looks very odd - the name of a namespace node is the ns prefix, which has no URI part. And in 2.0 the empty rule can of course be written with the pattern `match="i:*"`.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Thank you for noticing this. Fixed immediately.

Comment: This does work for the overly-simplified example I gave.  I've updated with a more realistic one.

Comment: @Tim-R: THere was no way I could know thw actual namespace you were using that `"i"` is bound to. Just replace in my answer `"i:i"` with `http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/` and the transformation produces exactly the wanted result.

Comment: @Tim-R: I made these mechanical changes and updated my answer. Please, never be in a hurry to say that something "is not working" :)